# Sorting an ArrayList made up of Numbers

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, numbers

So everything but the "sort" method was given as a template for the code. I know that I cannot simply do a Collections.sort because of the fact that there are integers and doubles. I'm guessing you would sort them like you would a regular array by just grabbing one and comparing them to the rest of the arraylist. Which you would have to create another arraylist? Am I on the right track with the two for loops?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Exercise13_03 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList < Number > list = new ArrayList <>();
    System.out.print("Enter five integers and five doubles: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      list.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      list.add(input.nextDouble());
    }

    sort(list);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
      System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
  }  
    public static void sort(ArrayList list) {
      for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
          for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++){


              }
          }
      }

    }
```

Comment: You could just use `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Number::doubleValue))`.

Comment: You can use [Arrays.sort(x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) from the java.util package to sort your array.

Comment: Since this is clearly an exercise, I doubt it's meant that he should be using the ready made `sort()` methods. However you don't need another `ArrayList` for sorting.

Comment: @Kayaman So would i just sort it as if i were sorting an array? Use a temp value to store the first variable and then compare to the rest of the arraylist?

Comment: You might want to study different sorting algorithms first. There's more than one way to skin a cat.